# How to share img in deep nested loop ? JS ANGULAR DEVEXTREME

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress, devextreme-angular

All my code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextrem-gallery?file=src/app/app.component.html

I need to share gallery in deep nested loop.
Problem is probably dataSource array.
Above code you can see how to print images in loop but i need to share same in galerry using dev extreme gallery.
I am open minded if you recommend me whatever solution here but only using gallery...

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @AakashGarg To display only images that belong to a specific json. All images are currently displayed.

Comment: @AakashGarg I have two item i json. Every item has a three images. Here in my code is printed all images .... six im for both card..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. Instead of a single Array of datasource have training id specific array by a map. so basically change your html to :-

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="box-one">
        <div class="header"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ng-container *ngIf="firstPage">
            <div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of aca.trainingExercises; let i = index;">
                <div class="single-exe">
                    <div class="holder-name">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="firstPage">
                            <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; justify-content: center; height: 100%;">
                                <!-- <div *ngFor="let singleImg of training.exercise.pictureList"
                                    style="width: 20%; height: 20vh; margin: 0 20px;">
                                    <img width="100%" height="100%" [src]="singleImg.url" alt="img exercise">
                                    <p class="description-below-img"> {{ truncate(singleImg.description) }}</p>
                                </div> -->
                                <dx-gallery #gallery id="gallery" [dataSource]="dataSourceImg.get(training.id)"
                                    [loop]="true" [height]="300" [showNavButtons]="true" [showIndicator]="true">
                                </dx-gallery>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

then change your datasource from an array to map like below :-

```
dataSourceImg: Map<number, string[]> = new Map();
```

then change your ngInit code to :-

```
this.aca.trainingExercises.forEach(training => {
      this.dataSourceImg.set(training.id, []);
      training.exercise.pictureList.forEach(img => {
        this.dataSourceImg.get(training.id).push(img.url);
      });
    });
```

**Working Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextrem-gallery-92fa1f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Ohh finally...you are god...But one more think. Can I share inside gallery or next gallery or below or above gallery only description ?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: just pass aca.description.

Comment: Where to pass ? Also can you explain me what is datasource.set and datasoruce.get ? SO THANK YOU. I will vote up!

Comment: datasource is a Map now of key value pair. read about map here :- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_maps_and_sets.htm

Comment: i don't know much about dx-gallery, so that you have to figure out.

Comment: You save me. Thank you. Vote for answear

Comment: Can you only save me with add descripiton text in stackblitz ? Where to set ?

Comment: where do you want the description? below each gallery?

Comment: Yes can below gallery

Comment: Oh sorry friend my mistake...no description...Every img has a own name... I need to show every name of img :(( sorry .

Comment: here I was confused because in the right json I also have a description. I made this json and copied it by hand to show an example of json ... the name of each picture should be displayed. sorry please.

Comment: can you help me please for this :( @AakasgGarg I need to share img name... for img.

Comment: You are ninjas of Js.... Thanks so much. You help me ..

Comment: Friend there is one big bug only...check console

Comment: ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current value: 'ngIf: 2'.

Comment: @jiwav894, i have fixed that on stackblitz.

Comment: Hmm bug is here ..i don't know what are you doing but i don't see change on stackblitz

Comment: @AakashGard can you help me please ?

Comment: @jiwav894 please check updated stackblitz url above.